# Unable to successfully run NUnit programmatically

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm currently trying to run tests programmatically, I have two solutions, one is a class library containing the tests and the other one is a console application. 
I want to run the tests contained in the DLL (the class library output) from the Console Application

Below the Code of the ClassLibrary

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        // TODO: Add your test code here
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        // TODO: Add your test code here
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And this is my Console Application code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{          
    TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage("Test");
    testPackage.Assemblies.Add(
           @"C:\DEV\NUnitConsole\NUnit.Tests\bin\Debug\NUnit.Tests.dll");

    RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
    remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
    TestResult result = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(),
             TestFilter.Empty, false, LoggingThreshold.Error);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Everything runs successfully however I never get a result of the test, it just says that is inconclusive.

```
{NUnit.Core.TestResult}
AssertCount: 0
Description: null
Executed: true
FailureSite: Test
FullName: "C:\\DEV\\NUnitConsole\\NUnit.Tests\\bin\\Debug\\NUnit.Tests.dll"
HasResults: false
IsError: false
IsFailure: false
IsSuccess: false
Message: null
Name: "C:\\DEV\\NUnitConsole\\NUnit.Tests\\bin\\Debug\\NUnit.Tests.dll"
ResultState: Inconclusive
Results: null
StackTrace: null
Test: {NUnit.Core.TestInfo}
Time: 0.0012101472641609884
```

Comment: I've tried the same thing - it seems to be working: I get ResultState as "Success" or "Failure", based on the test results. What version of Nunit are you using? maybe there's something else in your code that's creating this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `nunit3-console.exe`? You can execute with arguments, for example:

```
nunit3-console.exe "TestNunit.dll" -noresult
```

You can find `nunit3-console.exe` in:

> C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 20xx\Projects\\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0\tools

After installing with nuget `NUnit.ConsoleRunner`.